# recover headers value after split apache camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I have a xml where I'm using the split tag to process in Spring DSL.
What I'm doing is basically seaching for a value in the xml, when I find this value I need to get the value of another tag, child of the same element and save to a header. This operations seems simple, but I can't recover my headers outside split and I need to. I tried with headers and properties and the result was the same.

Please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code sample:

```
<route>
...
<split>
    <xpath>//FatherTag/ChildTag</xpath>
    <to uri="direct:processingRoute"/>
</split>

</route>

<route>
<from uri="direct:processingRoute"/>
<choice>
<when>
<simple>....</simple>
    <setHeader headerName="foo">
        <constant>test</constant>
    </setHeader>
</when>
</choice>

</route>
```

Comment: first of all, you are sure that the header inside the split is being set by your choice/when? Do you have some trace-level logs for us to see? I suspect it is because after the split, the resulting Exchange is the last exchange processed by the split unless you use an aggregation strategy

Comment: Well, I ended up creating a processor and did the xml parsing in java. But thanks, next time I'll go for AggregationStrategy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an `AggregationStrategy`. From [Camel Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

> **What the Splitter returns**
>
> **Camel 2.3 and newer**:
>
> The Splitter will by default return the original input message.
>
> **For all versions**
>
> You can override this by suppling your own strategy as an **AggregationStrategy**.

Your `AggregationStrategy` needs to check the appropriate header set for each child tag and pass it on the resulting Exchange output message for the split operation.

Comment: In camel forum I found some answers to related problems saying I would be able to get values outside split if I use properties instead of headers. I tried but no sucess. Any ideia on that? Or should I keep with AggregationStrategy.

Comment: As I said above, I solved it using a processor. However it's nice to know the right way to do it. ty!

Comment: @king_nl_ds I don't think using properties will make a difference. Properties are tied to a specific `Exchange` object. When splitting, camel creates individual `Exchange` objects for each piece. Adding a property on any of the sub Exchanges is not going to be accessible outside the split operation, unless you use an `AggregatorStrategy` to combine all the sub Exchanges into one aggregated Exchange, which becomes the output of the split operation.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source code for the Splitter processor in Camel 2.13.2,  it looks like it **might** propagate the properties from the sub Exchanges into the output Exchange regardless of the `AggregationStrategy`.

Comment: During my tests it didn't propagate. I guess it's as you said before, a indenpent exchange will be created for split.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve headers or properties set inside split function aggregation strategy needs to be used, if its simple header and need to avoid aggregation strategy then before split function set an exchange property with ArrayList as value

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();     
list.add("one");    
exchange.setProperty("list", list);
```

inside split function now if you update this property again with one more item to the list you will be able to retrieve it after split function is ended and will be available in each split exchange and parent exchange.

```
from("direct:main)   
.split(body())  
.to("direct:sub")  
.end().process(ex -> {
System.Out.Println(ex.getProperty("list"));
}).end();


from("direct:sub")  
.process(ex -> {  
List list = exchange.getProperty(list);  
list.add("two");  
exchange.setProperty(list);  
}).end();
```

Output: [one,two]