# Not able to update Camel exchange property

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am setting a property of camel exchange in route 1. I am trying to update the same in the second route inside a splitter. but in the second iteration of splitter i am getting the original value that I set in the route 1 instead of the new updated value. Below is the sample i am trying..

```
<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="route1">
<from uri="cxfrs://bean://test?synchronous=true"/>
        <bean ref="testBean" method="setMyProperty"/>// setting initial value for property
        <to uri="direct:directCall"/>
</route>

<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="route2">
    <from uri="direct:directcall"/>
    <log message="Inside Second call..."/>
    <split>
     <jsonpath>some Json path</jsonpath>
      <bean ref="formatConvertor" method ="convertLHMToJSON(${body})"/>

    <split>
      <jsonpath>some json path</jsonpath>
    <bean ref="PropertySetter" method ="setProperty"/> //I am setting new value in this method
     </split>
   </split>
```

Inside the beans:

```
   public void setMyProperty(Exchange exchange) {
            exchange.setProperty("testProp", "hello");
        }

    public void setProperty(Exchange exchange) {
           sysout(exchange.getProperty("testProp").toString())//this always prints "hello"
           String x=exchange.getProperty("testProp")+some other value;// in all iterations of split I am getting 'hello' as the value of the property instead of new value
            exchange.setProperty("testProp", x);
            sysout(exchange.getProperty("testProp").toString())// this line prints the new value
        }
```

Why the property is not updated? Even i tried setting in headers. same result. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a bean to set an exchange property? Unless there is more logic than shown, you can just do .setProperty("propertyName", "propertyValue"); You can then use the same code in your split to update the property.

Comment: Actually, I have many transformation in the bean before setting in the property. Again inside split i need to write business logic before i update the property.

Comment: It is a bit hard to handle from the code you have pasted why it doesn't work, I have updated exchange properties in the split before and that works fine. I think it is better if you test with a simple example. Put the SplitIndex in the exchange property and log that value. See that you can see that property during each split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a split-aggregate pattern and copy the property value during each iteration of the split from the old exchange to the new exchange because every time when the split iteration happens a new exchange is created from the source message (only carrying the properties & headers set before the split)
[recover headers value after split apache camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608310/recover-headers-value-after-split-apache-camel)